# Oracle 19c error while installing on Red Hat linux 9.1

Tags: oracle

Oracle 19c error while installing on Red Hat linux 9.1

"Error in invoking target ''libasmclntsh19.ohso libasmperl19.ohso client_sharedlib'' of makefile ins_rdbms.mk " [2760289.1]

after running the command ./runInstaller an error occurs when the oracle installation reached at 7%.

Comment: related?: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rnrdm/linux-platform-issues.html#GUID-32494E17-F05E-4E62-B988-D612DDEF0A82

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0), Oracle 19c is only supported on Red Hat Linux 7 and 8. There is no support for Red Hat 9.